# Получаю местоположения на русском, нужно на не русском

Tags: android, google-maps-api, android-location

Использую этот код, он делает все верно, выводит названия города. Но мне нужно это же названия только  латинскими буквами. Как это можно сделать ?

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());
try {
    List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
    Address obj = addresses.get(0);
    return obj.getAddressLine(1);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте применить ссылку "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;language=en" - здесь имеется выбор языка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выберете другую `Locale`, например `Locale.ENGLISH`. Сейчас на устройстве выбрана Русская.